# Is it possible to split a value by 2 delimiters in a rdd using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have tuples like this:

```
('id1', 'date;type;value\n2017-11-11 08:32:46.934;no_error;54.64325\n2017-11-11 08:32:47.356;no:error;35.46643\n')
```

And I want to split the value by ';' and '\n'. But I found I can't concatenate them and I don't know what to do instead. So far, I've got this:

```
rdd.mapValues(lambda t:  t.split(';'))
```

Is there any way I can split it by 2 delimiters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.split` splitting on regex `;|\n`:

```
import re
rdd.mapValues(lambda t:  re.split(';|\n', t))
```